# Error while updating property 'fill' of a view managed by: RNSVGReact

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to render a qrcode using this library: `react-native-qrcode-svg` but I have this error:

> Error while updating property 'fill' of a view managed by: RNSVGReact

I install the required package `react-native-svg` but the problem persist. I'm using the latest version of all packages.

This is the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

export default class MyQRCode extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <QRCode
        value="http://awesome.link.qr"
      />
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: You already tried to run `react-native link react-native-qrcode-svg && react-native-link react-native-svg && npx jetify` ?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior I'm using `expo`, is not necessary use `react-native link` or I'm wrong?

Comment: ah, you cant link using expo :(

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior Exactly, but in this situation how can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of 17 February 2020, installing the version 9.13.3 of react-native-svg is going to solve your problem.

Apparently, using expo install CLI is going to install the latest version of this package, but that's going to give you an error when you're starting the project(you'll see there specified what version of the package is supported by expo).

Just do something like:

```
yarn add react-native-svg@9.13.3
```

or

```
npm install react-native-svg@9.13.3
```

And you should be good to go.

See [this link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1117) for more info.

Comment: you saved me life :)

Comment: Downgrading works on an expo bare workflow app. Unfortunately, the error still persists on a react native project without expo.

Comment: Giving an update, for those using a react native project without expo, trying expo's version of react-native-svg solved it for me. `"react-native-svg": "git+https://github.com/expo/react-native-svg.git"`

Comment: So, November 2021 now, downgrading can't be the actual "answer" so does anybody know what the root issue was?

Comment: Some say 11.0.1 fixed their issue. I had to use 9.9.6 tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo run this command

```
expo install react-native-svg
```

Answer (score 0):

The v12.3.0 is working for me with Expo SDK 48